# About wiki API and cannot get proper response with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wikipedia-api

I was doing a mini project with AJAX, jQuery and some APIs. And the purpose is when you type in an address, it will show up a google street view in the background, some New York Times news and several wiki links about that city. The background pic and news parts worked fine but wiki part failed.

```
function loadData() {

var $body = $('body');
var $wikiElem = $('#wikipedia-links');
var $nytHeaderElem = $('#nytimes-header');
var $nytElem = $('#nytimes-articles');
var $greeting = $('#greeting');

// clear out old data before new request
$wikiElem.text("");
$nytElem.text("");

// load streetview
var st = $("#street").val();
var city = $("#city").val();
var address = st + ', ' + city;

$greeting.text("So, you want to live at " + address + "?");
var picUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=' + address + '';
// console.log(picUrl);
$body.append('  <img class="bgimg" src=" ' + picUrl + ' "> ');


var wikiUrl = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + city + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';
console.log(wikiUrl);

// var wikiRequstTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
//     $wikiElem.text("failed to get wikipedia resources");
// }, 8000);

$.ajax({
    url: wikiUrl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var articleList = response[1];

        for (var i = 0; i < articleList.length; i++) {
            articleStr = articleList[i];
            var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + articleStr;
            $wikiElem.append('<li><a href="' + url + '">' + articleStr + '</a></li>');
        };
        // clearTimeout(wikiRequstTimeout);
    }
});




return false;
};

$('#form-container').submit(loadData);
```

The response data I got is like

```
["new york city,ny", Array[0], Array[0], Array[0]]
```

and at index 1, it has 0 length, it's just an empty `[]`.

Have any suggestion?

Comment: It means there is no such article in Wikipedia. Try with "new york city, ny" (note the space after comma).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Fixed it.